# Beamer - Shaded Background in Block environment

Tags: beamer, shading

i would like to have a shaded coloured block title background in my beamer presentation. I could not figure out how to set the shading.
Any solution?

```
\documentclass[]{beamer} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=black!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=white,bg=black} 


\begin{document} 

\begin{frame} 

\begin{block}{Title which background color i like to shade} 
Block entry
\end{block} 

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `tcolobox` can be useful here. It provides the skin `beamer`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it might be the thing i am looking at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=black!70}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=white,bg=black}

\newtcolorbox{myblock}[2][]{beamer,title=#2,fonttitle=\sffamily,
  left=1mm,right=1mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,arc=2mm,
  colback=black,colupper=white,colframe=yellow,
  coltitle=black,title style={top color=red!70,bottom color=yellow},
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Title which background color i like to shade}
Block entry
\end{block}

\begin{myblock}{Title which background color i like to shade}
Block entry
\end{myblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tcolorbox inner theme as starting point and add a colour gradient like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=black!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=white,bg=black} 

\useinnertheme[rounded,shadow]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  title style={
    bottom color=cyan,
    top color=orange
  }
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame} 

\begin{block}{Title which background color i like to shade} 
Block entry
\end{block} 

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]